# IA32 vs MSR prefix for x86 MSR names

Tags: x86, intel, msr

Intel sometimes uses the `MSR_` prefix for MSR names, and sometimes `IA32_`, *even for the same MSR.*

For example, on SNB, in [SDM Volume 4](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm), they document both `IA32_PERF_STATUS` and `MSR_PERF_STATUS` for MSR `0x198` with somewhat different (but not exactly inconsistent<sup>1</sup>) values for the bits:

[image: Intel SDM Vol. 4]

What's up with that?

---

<sup>1</sup> In the sense that bits which are defined as *reserved* in the `IA32` version are given specific meaning in `MSR` version.

Answer (score 5):

Some MSR registers are architectural, meaning that they are guaranteed to be supported on all future processors (and the defined bit fields would have the same meaning in the future). Section 2.1 of the Intel SDM Volume 4 (October 2019) specifies that architectural MSRs have the prefix "IA32_" and all other MSRs are non-architectural.

> A subset of MSRs and associated bit fields, which do not change on
>   future processor generations, are now considered architectural MSRs.
>   For historical reasons (beginning with the Pentium 4 processor), these
>   “architectural MSRs” were given the prefix “IA32_”.

It's not necessary for an architectural MSR to have all of its bit fields to be architectural as well. MSR 198H is an architectural MSR since it's given the name `IA32_PERF_STATUS`. According to its architectural spec, bits 15:0 have some meaning and the rest of the MSR is reserved. If there are non-architectural bit fields in an architectural MSR, there are defined in a separate entry in the manual and the same MSR is given a name that is not prefixed with "IA32_". In this case, the non-architectural bit fields are defined under the name `MSR_PERF_STATUS`. These bit fields are not guaranteed to be supported (with the same meaning) in any other processor.

This naming convention was introduced after supporting some architectural MSRs. These MSRs were given names that may differ from this convention. Both the current names (according to the naming convention) and the former names are provided in the manual. Later MSRs have only names that follow the convention.

MSRs are architectural only with respect to a specific vendor, which is Intel in this case. The naming convention mentioned above is only followed Intel. Architectural MSRs on AMD processors don't have prefixes. So the term "architectural" in this context should be understood at the vendor level, not at the ISA level.

When MSRs were first introduced in the Pentium processors, they were called model-specific because Intel didn't want to commit to making any of them supported in any or all future x86 Intel processors. Starting with Pentium 4, Intel decided to make a subset of MSRs architectural and came up with that naming convention of prefixing these MSRs with the "IA32_" prefix which makes it easier for programmers to determine whether an MSR is architectural by just looking at its name. Although calling them "model-specific" is no longer technically accurate, but it stuck.